# Using intent send to pass string between apps not working onRestart()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get a string to pass between 2 apps but I'm having trouble with receiving the string. So far I've gotten it to work if the receiving app isn't open but not if it was previously running.

This seems to be down to the OnRestart() function where I'm trying to handle incoming string. Unlike OnCreate() I used for the start up handling of incoming string which returns SEND as it's intent. In the code below though the OnRestart() returns MAIN as it's intent.

```
@Override
protected void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    Log.v("VM","ONRESTART");
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.v("VM","INTENT: " + getIntent());
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.v("VM","ACTION: " + action);
    String type = intent.getType();
    Log.v("VM","TYPE: " + type);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) 
    {
        Log.v("VM","ACTION INTENT");
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) 
        {
            Log.v("VM","HANDLE TEXT");
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } 
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to get the right intent or do I need to do this another way with Broadcast Receivers or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override onNewIntent method for that

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_SEND) {

        //your code will be go here

    }
}
```

you can get more info here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29